# MySQL Timing Out using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 73,000 records.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT id, first_name, email 
FROM candidates 
WHERE first_name != 'DC3101 -' AND sent IS null
```

It completes in 0.0022 seconds and returns 9,000 records. I only want 4000 results so I ran this:

```
SELECT id, first_name, email 
FROM candidates 
WHERE first_name != 'DC3101 -' AND sent IS null LIMIT 4000
```

However this is causing the script to timeout and crash (I'm using `phpMyAdmin`).

Is there a particular performance issue with LIMIT clauses that I'm unaware of perhaps?

Comment: Though not directly related to your problem, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: I would usually agree. However I have 73,000 records and 4,000 are going to get an email each day but only get 1 email each. Basically this script just runs once a day to send an email to the next 4,000 people. The first_name clause will be taken out from day 3.

Please tell me though if that's a bad idea just seemed the easiest way.

Comment: That's my point. It's not the 'next' 4000 people. Without an ORDER BY clause, it's just 4000 people (who haven't been sent an email already).

Comment: How many candidates have the first name 'DC3101 -' ?

Comment: Fair point, updated it to ORDER BY first_name

Comment: Also that would be 64,000 - they are legacy candidates from a previous archive. The email i to let them know details are being deleted unless they want us to keep them.

Comment: Can you try the query in mysql CLI instead of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour. Maybe try rebuilding the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate this behaviour (in InnoDB, anyway)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS candidates;

CREATE TABLE candidates 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,sent TINYINT NULL
);

SELECT COUNT(*) total, SUM(first_name = 'DC3101') dc FROM candidates;
+-------+-------+
| total | dc    |
+-------+-------+
| 73000 | 64000 |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

SELECT id,first_name FROM candidates WHERE first_name != 'DC3101' AND sent IS NULL ORDER BY id LIMIT 4000;
+-------+------------+
| id    | first_name |
+-------+------------+
| 64001 | IJ7686     |
...
| 68000 | XI8405     |
+-------+------------+
4000 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

Perhaps the table is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks I believe you are correct. Upon further investigation there were a few characters that conflicted with the character set. Lord knows how that happened (not my data) but it's more manageable to do 1,000 chunks and throw the exceptions up as an error. I've basically got it running as a scheduled PHP task with error logging for the bad lines. There's not too many so will just manually sort those (we're talking dozens in the whole thing).

Comment: Thank you by the way. I appreciate you taking the time to do all that.